# Recovering data from a drive

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I have a server that was running Centos 6. It's been humming along for a few years and I have been backing up data off it on regular basis. All of sudden, and after a reboot, it came up in read-only mode. I think one of the folders failed to back up properly, and I would like to access the data. Here's what I did:

Got a new hard drive installed on the system.

Installed Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop on it.

Booted up from the new drive.

When I do:

```
lsblk -l
```

It tells me that I have two drives, partitioned as follows:

```
sdb
  ----- sdb1  459.8 G
  ----- sdb2  8 K
  ----- sdb3  6 G

sda
  ----- sda1   102 M
  ----- sda2   649 G
```

sdb is the new boot drive
sda is the old boot drive

I can mount sda1 fine

When I try to mount sda2, I get the following error message:

```
unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

Any idea what I can do to get to the data on /dev/sda2?

Comment: Do you know what LVM means? Have you read [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/index.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mount it because it's a LVM Physical volume, not a logical volume.

First, make a disk scan:

```
#lvmdiskscan
#lvscan
```

Get the LV and VG names
    #lvdisplay
You must see something like this:

```
--- Logical volume --- 
LV Name /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 
VG Name VolGroup00
...
```

Now you must mount the partition:

```
#mount /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /mnt/old
```

Ah! I assume you have lvm2 installed and the kernel modules loaded.

Comment: I had some additional issues because it was a RAID1 volume, so I had to disconnect one of the disks before I was able to get the correct LVM info